# Send alert to external unpaid users

Tags: designer-workflow, 2016

I have a customer list with email column for each customer

In the list, there is a paid status for the annual subscription, if the customer pay the Paid status will be changed to true!

These customers not in the domain directory, 
  We need to send to unpaid customers an alert before one week from the end subscription date

How can send alert to external users who didn't pay in SharePoint workflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better but more complicated way is to create site workflow, that will start every day and will do the calculation of days till subscription date and then (if 7 days and status eq unpaid) send email.

An easier way is to create list workflow and set pause until subscription date minus 7 days, then check status and send email.

The third way is to use  Information policies as described [here](https://blog.splibrarian.com/2013/03/27/setting-up-automated-reminder-emails/). You can create another date field and set date value(subscription date minus 7 days) then configure Information policy based on this field.